# Get overloaded default member using reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically invoke the indexer on an object, given an integer parameter. E.g.

```
Public Class MyC
        Default Public ReadOnly Property Items(index As Integer) As String
            Get
                Return "Integer indexer"
            End Get
        End Property

        Default Public ReadOnly Property items(x As String) As String
            Get
                Return "String indexer"
            End Get
        End Property
End Class
```

...

```
dim obj as MyC = new MyC()
dim result as string = obj(10) 'Invoke property without using reflection
```

If I want to call the indexer dynamicaly, without assuming specific property names, and with regard to the fact that the indexer may be overloaded, I can do this:

```
Dim a As Object = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, obj, {10})
Dim b As Object = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("", Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, obj, {"str"})
```

These lines conveniently determine which indexer to call based on the parameter array I pass in.

Now if possible I want to improve performance by actually storing the property (as a PropertyInfo object) so it's not necessary to recompute the property each time I call it.

**Is there a way to retrieve a specific overload of the default member indexer and actually store the method without invoking it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim obj = new MyC()

' Get all default members
Dim defaultmembers = obj.GetType().GetDefaultMembers().Cast(Of PropertyInfo)()

' Get the 'Int32' overload the hard way
Dim intIndex = defaultmembers.Single(Function(m) m.GetGetMethod().GetParameters().Single().ParameterType = GetType(Integer))

' Get the 'String' overload the easy way :-)
Dim stringIndex = defaultmembers.Single(Function(m) m.ToString().Contains("[System.String]"))

' create delegates
Dim intFunc As Func(Of Int32, String) = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of Int32, String)), obj, intIndex.GetGetMethod())
Dim strFunc As Func(Of String, String) = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of string, String)), obj, stringIndex.GetGetMethod())

' Now you can call them
Console.WriteLine(intFunc(10))
Console.WriteLine(strFunc("12"))
```